# Linux/slattach - ip over serial

Tags: linux, networking, serial

I trying to run TCP/IP Over Serial communication, as instructed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890505/socat-tunnel-ip-through-tty

I entered a command:

```
root# slattach -s 19200 -p slip /dev/ttyS2
```

And the system returned an error:

```
slattach: TIOCSETD: Invalid argument
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `TIOCSETD` is "set line discipline". Did you try as root? Your kernel has SLIP enabled?